# F1 visa in the USA: should off-campus work that takes place outside the US be approved by the USCIS?

Tags: usa, student-visa

I am an international graduate student under F1 visa in the USA. If I perform some work outside the USA, should that work be approved by the USCIS?

On the page ["Employment" (ICE)](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/employment) I read that:

> Off-campus work authorization requires case-by-case approval from
> USCIS. Approval is not based on the student's choice of employer.

but I wonder whether it only concerns work in the USA.

Comment: Are you asking about work you perform remotely while you are in the U.S.? Or are you asking about work you perform while you are outside the U.S.?

Comment: @user102008 Actually I am interested in both.

Answer (score 3):

You said in comments that you wanted to know about both if you are inside the U.S. and outside.

If you are outside the U.S., you do not have a U.S. immigration status. You only have a status while in the U.S. Since you are not in F1 status, you are not subject to the conditions of F1 status, and you cannot "violate" a status you do not have. You may have a visa stamp in your passport, but that is just permission to travel to the U.S. in the future.

If you are inside the U.S. and are asking about working remotely for a foreign employer, as Karlson says, there is some debate an disagreement about this.